# Is the truncated squared expected value less than the variance?

Tags: variance, truncated-distributions

Let the continuous random variable $X$ be distributed with mean $\mu_x$ and variance $\sigma^2_x$ with support $[0, \infty]$.

Let the random variable $Y$ be the right truncation of $X$, with truncation point $a$.

[One can find conditons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885964/truncated-variance-less-than-variance) for when $\mathtt{Var}[Y] \le \mathtt{Var}[X]$.

Is it true that $\mathbf{E}[(Y-\mu_x)^2] \le \mathbf{E}[(X-\mu_x)^2]= \mathtt{Var}[X] =\sigma^2_x$? How would one show this?

Expressed differently, if $f_X(x)$ is the probability distribution of $X$, then the probability distribution of $Y$ is $f_Y(x)= b f_X(x)$ where
$$
b=\frac{1}{\int_0^{a}f_X(x) dx} \ge 1.
$$

Can one find conditions for which
$$
 \int_{0}^{a} (x-\mu_x)^2 b f_{X}(x) dx  \le 
         \int_{0}^{a} (x-\mu_x)^2 f_{X}(x) dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} (x-\mu_x)^2 f_{X}(x) dx?
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in general.

Let it be that $\mu_x>a$.

Then $Y(\omega)\leq a$ assures that $(Y(\omega)-\mu_x)^2\geq(\mu_x-a)^2$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Consequently $\mathbb E(Y-\mu_x)^2\geq(\mu_x-a)^2$.

However, nothing prevents us to choose $X$ is such a way that $\mathsf{Var}(X)<(\mu_x-a)^2$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Might it then hold for the case $\mu_x <a$?